# redirect to default locale with detectBrowserLanguage enabled

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

I have `nuxt-i18n` module installed And I'm trying to redirect to the default locale `defaultLocale :'it'` with `detectBrowserLanguage` enabled .

what is expected is to force redirect to default locale if its set but i always get the browser language set in the cookie .

my config :

```
 defaultLocale: "it",
    detectBrowserLanguage: {
      alwaysRedirect: true,
      fallbackLocale: "it",
      redirectOn: "root",
      useCookie: true,
      cookieDomain: null,
      cookieKey: "lang",
      cookieSecure: true,
    },
```

is this possible ? because if i disabled the detect broswer there will be no cookie and the selected lang will not be saved.

I'm using nuxt 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling `alwaysRedirect: true`